# A problem about a non-linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the equation $x''(t)+x'(t)+x^3(t)=0$ with $x(0)=1$ and $x'(0)=0$ how to prove that

1. $ \mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to  + \infty } x\left( t \right) = 0 $.
2. For every $t>0$ it is $x(t)>0$.

the second question is what I really need. This problem is from G. Gallavotti "The elements of Mechanics"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the energy function $E=\frac12 x'^2+\frac14x^4$, then the time derivative of that is
$$
E'=x'(x''+x^3)=-x'^2\le 0.
$$
The only solution that has $x'=0$ constantly is the stationary solution $x=0$. All other solutions continuously lose energy and fall towards the state $E=0$.

The second question is more complicated, you have to show that the friction is over-critical, so that no oscillation occurs. The equation $x''+x^3=0$ without friction is conservative and oscillates along the level curves of $E$, for a small friction coefficient this oscillation persists, giving a spiral in phase space.

[image]

As this plot of $x(t)$ shows, a friction coefficient of $0.8$ still crosses the zero line, any proof method for 2. must be quite specific for $c>0.9$.

Comment: For the first question I got the same conclusion of your answer. The problem is exactly the second. How to prove that we have no oscillations.

Comment: I got all these conclusions by myself but the problem is how to prove the last statement analytically. According to the author of the book it is possible but I'm stuck.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your job.

Comment: In zooms for $c\in[0.9,1]$ it looks like it has a boundary layer. You can write it as system $x'+cx=v$, $v'=-x^3$, where in some sense the first is the "fast" and the second the "slow" equation. Then when $x$ is small enough, $v$ is slow moving while the first equation restores its equilibrium at $x=v/c$. Insert this approximation into the second to get $cx'=-x^3\implies x^{-2}(t)-x^{-2}(t_1)=2(t-t_1)/c$ as long-time behavior. I'm just not sure how to prove how exact this is, what "small enough" is, and how to connect to the initial piece.